# Need help identifying FFC connector

Tags: identification, connector, ffc

I broke the latch of a 16-pin, 0.5 mm pitched FFC connector on my Kinesis Advantage360 Pro keyboard and I want to find a suitable latch replacement.

Could any one identify the exact connector in the photo? The ruler in the photo is in millimeters.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: It looks like a Tyco part. Check for bottom side, 0.5mm pitch, right angle, 16 positions.

Comment: The exact part probably doesn't matter. Anything with the same number of pins, pitch & bottom contact would do - there are many manufacturers of these. The layout of the 2 mechanical pads on the sides may vary a bit, as well as the contact type - some you just pull, some you pull and flip up a bit.

Answer (score 1):

That is a Slider FFC socket, 0.5 mm, RA SMD, bottom contacts. You'll need to replace the socket. You can't replace just the slider.

I identified it with my [Identiconn](https://connectorbook.com/identification.html). It appears to be a [Amphenol ICC (FCI) Aorora F32R](https://connectorbook.com/identification.html?m=NN&n=ffc_fpc_slider_sockets&s=Aorora%20F32R).

[image: Amphenol ICC (FCI) Aorora F32R]

{Digikey}

https://www.digikey.ee/en/products/detail/amphenol-cs-fci/F32R-1A7H1-11016/11564634

https://www.amphenol-cs.com/product-series/0-50mm-ffc-fpc-connectors.html

Comment: "You can't replace just the slider." - Do you mean that it is near-impossible to remove the slider from the new socket without breaking it?
(To give you an idea of my knowledge on electrical components, I didn't even know that, to remove the cable from the socket I was supposed to just pull the slider until the latch stopped me from pulling it any further.)

Comment: @KIYZ The plastics holding the slider in place may be damaged as well, these aren't really designed to be removed. On some models you can (accidentally) remove it without damaging it, on some you can't. Replacing the whole component will be a PITA however, these are very difficult to desolder and mount by hand. You'll need help from an experienced soldering technician.

Comment: What is the role of the two hooks on the slider? Are they a convenience feature, much like the screws on some laptop computers' bottom covers that remain secured to prevent loss? They don't appear to influence the cable-locking mechanism.

Comment: I'm asking this because I'm starting to think that I should think of a decent solution that doesn't require a socket replacement first. Here's my concern: if I reuse the broken slider, could vibrations from transportation of the keyboard loosen the slider?

Comment: " could vibrations from transportation of the keyboard loosen the slider? " Maybe. "What is the role of the two hooks on the slider?" to keep the slider from falling off.